How can I get the dates when a card was moved between any columns in a GitHub projectV2 using GraphQL API?
Since we don't have a way to trigger any event when a card changes columns on a ProjectV2 board, I'm trying to get those dates from the API so I can update the issues with custom fields.
My goal is to have one custom field for each column in our board, and I want to store the date when the card entered that column into this custom field.
Something like:
Custom field: "In progress"
Value: "2024-06-27"

Custom field: "In review"
Value: "2024-07-02"

This way  so I can calculate how long an issue spent in each column (which is a very basic metric to have).
I can already get other dates like creation_date or closing_date via the API and update custom fields, but I cannot find anywhere where to get the column changes dates from the API.
Is this something we can get from the API? I've been searching and experimenting high and low for a couple months already and I cannot seem to figure this one out.
